# Combine all csv files into one single csv inside AWS CLI

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I have a S3 bucket with a folder called batches. Inside the batches folder, I have 20 CSV files. Using AWS ClI (or a bash file to be exact), how can I combine all these csv files into a single CSV file and move it up one folder.

Normally in terminal this is how I do it:

```
cd batches && cat ./*csv > combined.csv
```

What would be a comparable way to do this for an S3 bucket inside AWS CLI?

Comment: I think you have to copy the files somewhere first, and the upload the jointed file. You could also use Athena to query all these separate files if this is what you want to do.

Comment: @Marcin Thanks! I ended up changing my strategy altogether since this seems to be an overkill for what I needed.

Answer (score 1):

If you only have 20 CSV files in total, then Marcin's suggestion is probably the right way to go. If you have more bigger-sized CSV, then I would suggest taking advantage of multipart upload in S3 and processing them in aws lambda.